# Android:ArrayList storing weird values

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I just don't understand what's going on here.

```
ArrayList<ListItem> list=new ArrayList<ListItem>();
ListItem curItem=new ListItem();
String[] contents=cwFile.list();
for(int i=0;i<contents.length;i++){
    curItem.itemName = contents[i];
    if(new File(cwd+contents[i]).isDirectory()){
        curItem.isDir=true;
    }
    list.add(i,curItem);
}
Log.i("Main",list.get(0).itemName);
Log.i("Main",contents[0]);
```

So in this code snippet, I get the contents of a directory using the File.list() method

Then, I store the names in an `ArrayList` of `ListItem` objects, where `ListItem` is a self-created class.

But, `ListItem` is just a class that stores the string

```
class ListItem {
    protected String itemName ="";
    protected boolean isDir=false;
    protected Double size=0.0;
}
```

However, after logging the first elements of both the array and the `ArrayList` (last 2 lines of the first code snippet), I get different results!

This is the log output:

```
03-15 20:29:46.427 465-465/com.harshal.filer I/filer: .userReturn
03-15 20:29:46.427 465-465/com.harshal.filer I/filer: Android
```

The second output,"Android" is an actual directory on the device.
But what's ".userReturn" and where did it come from???

Comment: Hint: you're only ever creating a single instance of `ListItem`. You're then adding many references to that same object. That's a mistake... As for `.userReturn`, that's file or directory, but files starting with `.` are hidden by default...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to the following:

```
ArrayList<ListItem> list=new ArrayList<ListItem>();
String[] contents=cwFile.list();
for(int i=0;i<contents.length;i++){
    ListItem curItem=new ListItem();
    curItem.itemName = contents[i];
    if(new File(cwd+contents[i]).isDirectory()){
        curItem.isDir=true;
    }
    list.add(i,curItem);
}
Log.i("Main",list.get(0).itemName);
Log.i("Main",contents[0]);
```

You see I moved

```
 ListItem curItem=new ListItem();
```

into the for-loop. If it's outside the reference of the item at position 0 in the list will always point to the latest entry in your array, thus the weird result.